# Fetching Files from SD card and USB to different folders when using getExternalStorage()

Tags: android

Is it possible to sort the files detected from usb and SD Card seperately?.I mean I fornd that using getExternalStorage,we are able to detect all external devices connected to Android device which includes both SD card and USB.

I would like to seperate the files that are detected to 2 seperate folders(Now the files from SD card and USB are detected into same folder)..ie USB files seperately and SD card files seperately.

How to do it?Kindly help

Comment: I also have the same problem..I am using Android's Mediastore to list all the Music and video files.
When i connect USB in my tablet it will automatically detect all the Media files from the USB device and list it with the Media files already present in the tablet..

Is there any other way we can separate media files from USB and sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

You have to code in the logic to determine if the "external storage" is really external storage.  Different devices use a different name - very stupid I agree.  In Google's API doc's I'm pretty sure they mention that getExternalStorage() is not guaranteed to grab the external storage as this is manufacturer and device specific.

Knowing this pitfall may assist you in a solution.

Comment: But right now external storage includes the sdcard(not external sdcard.. haven tried with that) and also all other devices like usb (pendrives,mp3 players etc) connected to it.So getExternalStorage fetches from all available devices.I wanted to know if like in PCs,is it possible to create a seperate folder or something when a usb is connected to a tablet(android)

Comment: @PoojaBalakrishnan It works just like a PC (linux) system does.  If you look in ADB Shell you will see there is a /mnt that lists all the devices available. You might try to play around with the different "external, internal storage" location to check if a different device is being selected than what is thought.